# Expressjs Pass Body Values to Res.Locals on Error

Tags: express, error-handling, body-parser

I am trying to capture the values located in the form inputs on form submission when an error occurs to then be passed into the same input fields after the error redirect. To achieve this, I have set `res.locals.errorFormValue` to `req.body` in the `catch()` portion of my POST route, but I don't see any value when I `console.log(res.locals)` ing the GET route. Am I saving the value in the right spot? Is there a better way to save the input field values on POST with error to be used in the rendered view?

Here is my POST route:

```
.post(function(req, res){

            models.Post.create({
                title: req.body.title,
                discovery: req.body.discovery,
                userId: req.user.userId     
            }).then(function(){
                req.flash('info', 'Post was successfully created.');
                res.redirect('/app');
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err)

                console.log(req.body);

                res.locals.errorFormValue = req.body;

                var errMessage = [];

                var errStatusArray = err.errors;
                console.log(errStatusArray);

                //Push message value in objects to array
                for(var prop in errStatusArray){
                    errMessage.push(errStatusArray[prop].message);
                }

                errMessage = errMessage.join(" ")

                req.flash('error', errMessage);
                res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is the GET:

```
.get(function(req, res){
        models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
            where: {
                organizationId: req.user.organizationId
            }
        }).then(function(category){
                console.log(res.locals);
                res.render('pages/app/post-create.hbs',{
                    category: category,
                    errorMessage: req.flash('error'),
                    csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
                });
            });
        });
    })
```

view template accessing locals variable:

```
<p>{{errorFormValue.title}}</p>
<p>{{errorFormValue.discovery}}</p>
```